# Pushing to array doesn't trigger vue's reactivity

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I already know that editing object within an array doesn't work for vue.js due to its limited capability and base on what I read using vue.set should solve this problem easily but I am having a hard time making it work.

this is my sample data. The parent object is called resource and inside resource there are power_generator_groups , inside the power_generator_groups are power_generators.

```js
{
  "id": 5,
  "bg_member_id": 1,
  "code": "G0633",
  "name": "namex1",
  "power_generator_groups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "resource_id": 5,
      "code": "GC033",
      "power_generators": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "power_generator_group_id": 1,
          "code": "XXXXX",
          "name": "test",
          "contract_number": "00000003",
          "supply_max": 1000,
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "power_generator_group_id": 1,
          "code": "XXXXX",
          "name": "test",
          "contract_number": "00000003",
          "supply_max": 1000,
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "power_generator_group_id": 1,
          "code": "XXXXX",
          "name": "test",
          "contract_number": "00000003",
          "supply_max": 1000,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "resource_id": 5,
      "code": "GC033",
      "contract_number": "065C001",
      "power_generators": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "power_generator_group_id": 2,
          "code": "XXXXX",
          "name": "test",
          "contract_number": "00000003",
          "supply_max": 1000,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my vue file

```js
<template lang="pug">
  .wrapper
    .animated.fadeIn
      b-container(fluid='')
        b-row.my-1
          b-col(sm='3')
            label(:for='`type-key`') companyName
          b-col(sm='9')
            b-form-select(v-model='item.bg_member_id' :options="companyList")
          b-col(sm='3')
            label(:for='`type-key`') code
          b-col(sm='9')
            b-form-input(v-model='item.code')

        b-button(size='sm', @click='addPowerGeneratorGroup', variant="primary")
          | Add power_generator_group
        template(v-for='(group, group_index) in item.power_generator_groups')
          b-card(
            header-tag="header"
            footer-tag="footer"
            )
            div(slot="header")
              i.fa.fa-align-justify
              strong power_generator_groups
              button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm(type='button' @click='deletePowerGeneratorGroup(group_index)')
                span.fa.fa-trash-o
            div
            b-row.my-1
              b-col(sm='3')
                label(:for='`type-key`')
                  | code
              b-col(sm='9')
                b-form-input(v-model='group.code')
              b-col(sm='3')
                label(:for='`type-key`') group name
              b-col(sm='9')
                b-form-input(v-model='group.name')
              b-col(sm='3')
                label(:for='`type-key`') contract number
              b-col(sm='9')
                b-form-input(v-model='group.contract_number')
              b-container.bv-example-row(fluid='')
                b-button(size='sm', @click='addPowerGenerator(group_index)', variant="primary")
                  | add power_generator
              b-card(
                header-tag="header"
                footer-tag="footer"
                )
                div(slot="header")
                  i.fa.fa-align-justify
                  strong power_generators
                  b-table(small v-bind:item="group.power_generators" v-bind:fields="fields" fixed responsive)
                    template(v-for="field in fields" :slot="field.key" slot-scope="contract")
                      template(v-if="field.key == 'actions'")
                        b-button(size='sm', @click='deletePowerGenerator(group_index, contract.index)', variant="primary")
                          | Del
                      template(v-else)
                        b-form-input(:type='types[field.key]' v-model = 'contract.item[field.key]')


        b-button(size='sm', @click='save', variant="primary")
          | Save
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
  export default {
    props: {
      item: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: () => {
        }
      },
      companyList: Array
    },
    data() {
      return {
        companyId: null,
        code: null,
        name: null,
        contract_number: null,
        fields: [
          {key: 'actions', label: '' },
          {key: 'code', label: 'code', sortable: true, sortDirection: 'desc'},
          {key: 'name', label: 'name', sortable: true, class: 'text-center'},
          {key: 'contract_number', label: 'contractNo'},
          {key: 'supply_max', label: 'maxunit'}
        ],
        types: {
          code: 'text',
          name: 'text',
          contract_number: 'text',
          supply_max: 'number'
        },
        items: 
        {}
      }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {
    addPowerGenerator(index) {
      console.log(index)
      console.log(this.item)
      const pgg = this.item.power_generator_groups[index];
      const pgs = pgg.power_generators || Vue.set(pgg, 'power_generators', []);
      pgs.push(
        {
          "code": "",
          "name": "",
          "contract_number": "",
          "supply_max": "",
        }
      )
    },
    addPowerGeneratorGroup() {
      const pggs = this.item.power_generator_groups || Vue.set(this.item, 'power_generator_groups', []);
      pggs.push(
        {
          "resource_id": this.item.id,
          "name": "",
          "code": "",
          "contract_number": "",
          "power_generators": []
        }
      )
    },
      deletePowerGenerator(group_index, field_index) {
        this.item.power_generator_groups[group_index].power_generators.splice(field_index, 1);
      },
      deletePowerGeneratorGroup(group_index) {
        this.item.power_generator_groups.splice(group_index, 1);
      },
      save: function () {
        this.$parent.save(this.item)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am guessing it's because the address in memory for the array does not change when push, so the change is not detected.

Comment: what are the work around for this problem ? I tried vue.set but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `Vue.set` only if you have `power_generator_groups` that have no `power_generators` property, since Vue can't detect when you add it otherwise. 
 Assuming there are no problems with your template (you didn't show it), change your `addPowerGenerator` method:

```js
addPowerGenerator(index) {
  console.log(index)
  console.log(this.item)
  const pgg = this.item.power_generator_groups[index];
  const pgs = pgg.power_generators || Vue.set(pgg, 'power_generators', []);
  pgs.push(
    {
      "code": "",
      "name": "",
      "contract_number": "",
      "supply_max": "",
    }
  )
}
```

`Vue.set` returns the property you just created which is how `pgs` contains the proper reference in that case.

Do the same thing for the new method you edited in:

```js
addPowerGeneratorGroup() {
  const pggs = this.item.power_generator_groups || Vue.set(this.item, 'power_generator_groups', []);
  pggs.push(
    {
      "resource_id": this.item.id,
      "name": "",
      "code": "",
      "contract_number": "",
      "power_generators": []
    }
  )
}
```

[You can see a mockup here](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/jg9y8cvz/) where I've assumed `this.item` refers to the resource itself.  I included a 3rd group which has no `power_generators` property for testing.

Comment: still not working for me , I thought this would work but I think the problem is on my other method. I updated the question can you check?

Comment: @obliviousfella - If you read my answer carefully you will see that it solves the problem with the new method you just posted too.  You'll need to use `Vue.set` in the same way.  I updated the mockup to show you.

Comment: I tried replacing my code with your jsfiddle , but I can't seem to make it work , the array is getting updated in console.log but it just doesn't reflect the changes in my UI. maybe my template has problems?

Comment: It must be, or there is an error in other code somewhere.

Comment: the weird thing is the add power generator group is working fine even before.. I just can't make it work for power generator

Comment: I don't know :) I've shown the solution utilizing what you've provided.  You should try to place all of my code into your project, both the template and component, because you can see that it works.  You can also show your template if you want.

Comment: Hello , I am sorry for not pasting the whole code in the first place. I updated it now :D

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  I would recommend starting your template from scratch using mine as a baseline.  Get it to work with that first and see what happens.

Comment: I found the problem and it is weird it doesn't have any connection with the question at all.

Comment: If I use the props being passed to this component this problem occurs but when I use the data within this component the code works ( even my code before )

Comment: Good catch.  I wondered if props might come into play.  Feel free to ask another question on SO about the props if you want.  You can upvote this answer or not if it helped you.

Comment: since it helped me find out the problem , i m gonna upvote , thanks for the time.

Comment: just to help everyone out. Never use the keyword "item" for props. It will ruin your day.

Comment: I fixed everything by not using the word "item" for props instead I replaced it with my model name.

Comment: It's not a reserved word in JavaScript or Vue so there's no reason it would be intrinsically harmful.  It probably has to do with a misunderstanding in the interplay between a binding/prop and model somewhere if I had to guess.  Or maybe a 3rd party library.  Either way, glad you figured it out.

Comment: something in my component is messing with the word item. I never found out the reason I just assumed it is somewhat reserved.